# Qtiles won't work with Range Scale

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS with QTiles plugins.

It was working perfectly, until I use Scale Range within my style.
When I do so, the Scaled Range layer is not printed at all on the generated png.

Do you know why?

Comment: It looks like each generated tile are done from 1:10000000 range scale.

I am looking throw the code to fix that...

Comment: Here is some code :

 scale = self.scaleCalc.calculate(self.projector.transform(tile.toRectangle()), self.width)
  
        self.settings.setExtent(self.projector.transform(tile.toRectangle()))
        job = QgsMapRendererSequentialJob(self.settings)
        job.start()
        job.waitForFinished()
        image = job.renderedImage()
        self.writer.writeTile(tile, image, self.format, self.quality)

maybe we need to put the computed scale on self.settings somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ! I found the solution by fixing QTiles plugin.

It was because Qtiles never tell QGIS the current zoom level when generating tiles.

Just add
self.settings.setMapUnits(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3395').mapUnits())

in render function inside tilingthread.py inside C:\Users[yourname].qgis2\python\plugins\qtiles

Comment: Please consider submitting a pull request with the fix at https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles

Comment: Jobs done ! https://github.com/nextgis/QTiles/pull/41